# Delphi TeeChart drawing on canvas

Tags: delphi, canvas

I am using delphi 10.3 TeeChart to map out some points.

After mapping these points out, I want to generate lines between these points.

So basically a line from Point A to Point B

```
chart1.Canvas.Pen.Color := ClYellow;
chart1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 2;
chart1.Canvas.MoveTo(Chart1.Axes.Bottom.CalcXPosValue(chart1.Series[0].XValues[WayPoint]),Chart1.Axes.left.CalcYPosValue(Chart1.Series[0].YValues[WayPoint]));
chart1.Canvas.LineTo(Chart1.Axes.Bottom.CalcXPosValue(chart1.Series[0].XValues[WayPoint+1]),Chart1.Axes.left.CalcYPosValue(Chart1.Series[0].YValues[WayPoint+1]));
```

That code is run on the AfterDraw event of chart1, It is run under a for I := 1 to Points (number of waypoints).

The Result I get is as follows :

[image: a]

Any help or suggestions would be great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `I` is the same as `Waypoint`, note that series value lists are indexed from `0` to `NPoints - 1`, so  for `I := 1 to Points` looks strange.

Moreever, to connect points, you need `NPoints - 1` segments, so loop should count from `0` to `NPoint - 2`  (to avoid out of array at `WayPoint+1`)

And the main doubt - why do you draw lines "by hands" while `TChart` was intended for this purpose?